# How to create records in has_many through association in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I have two models (User and Event) with multiple has_many through associations, where my current association is by the below logic:

1. User can participate in many events through EventGroup
2. Event has many users through EventGroup
3. User can like many events through Eventgroup
4. Event has many user likes through Eventgroup

**Model:**

```
class User
 has_many :event_groups
 has_many :events,:through => :event_groups
 has_many :event_likes,:through => :event_groups,:class_name => "Event"
end

class Event
  has_many :event_groups
  has_many :users,:through => :event_groups
  has_many :user_likes,:through => :event_groups,:class_name => "User"
end

class EventGroup
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user_like,:class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :event_like,:class_name => "Event"
end
```

**EventGroup columns:**

```
user_id
event_id
user_like_id
event_like_id
```

After setting up the association I tried to create the association record with the below code:

```
user = User.first
user.event_likes << Event.first  
user.save
```

[image]
***Here the record is created with user_id & event_like_id instead of `user_like_id & event_like_id***

But I am not able to get the User records by **`event.user_likes`**, so I checked my eventgroup record. It has the `nil value for user_like_id.`

```
#<EventGroup id: 24, event_id: 1, user_id: 2,event_like_id: 1, user_like_id: nil>
```

Let me know the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Using the .where format, you can pass a string like .where("event_groups.user_like_id  = ?", 17) to qualify the joined taggings table.

For example:

```
User.joins(:event_groups).where("event_groups.user_like_id = ?", 17)
```

Comment: I am not asking the steps to retrieve the records, I want to know the way to add records properly.

Comment: I am answered your line "But I am not able to get the User records by event.user_likes". You used `get` and that is the `get` query but not `add`.

Comment: the problem is user_like_id is nil always, so its not possible to retrieve the record by your query

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you may need to define `inverse_of` in your `has_many` relations:

```
class User
 #...
 has_many :event_likes, :through => :event_groups, :inverse_of => :user_likes, :class_name => "Event"
end

class Event
  #...
  has_many :user_likes, :through => :event_groups, :inverse_of => :event_likes, :class_name => "User"
end
```

See the chapter on [`:through` in the doc of `has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)

Comment: no luck with inverse_of :(
While adding the records event_id is updated instead of event_like_id

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to model two many-to-many relationships (Users-Participate-In-Events and Users-Like-Events) that are distinct concepts in one relationship. I'm assuming here that a User can Participate in an Event without Liking it, and vice-versa. In that case, keep `EventGroup` modeled to only represent the Participation relationship, and create another  `EventLikes` model to represent the Likes. The columns in the two tables would be the same, but represent the different relationships. After that, adding the Event to either (events, or event_likes) should work

Answer (score 0):

I create similar relationship between same models (User-User) through Relationship model,
my code:

`has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy`

`has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed`

`has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
           class_name: "Relationship",
           dependent: :destroy`

`has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower`